# Memory leak in event handler for a file read stream when processing lines with an object lookup

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, v8

I want to read a large file (~250M lines) in nodejs and perform some simple processing on each line. Since the file is so large, I want to read it one line at time.

The processing steps on each line are as follows:

1. Split the line by tabs (it's a tab-separated file)
2. Grab the first field in the line, which is an ID
3. Check if the ID exists in an object, and if so do some processing

Right now I can read the file one line at a time using Node's readline package and memory usage is around 50MB. However, when I combine certain steps I get a memory leak that I can't resolve: memory usage climbs over 2GB within 60s or so on my machine. I've done some diagnosis, but can't resolve the issue, likely due to my poor understanding of garbage collection.

Below is a code snippet that will cause a memory leak and after it are alternatives that do not. It seems that combining destructuring of the line fields and using a field for object lookup causes the leak, but destructuring of the line fields or object lookup on their own do not.

#### This causes a memory leak

This is the exact code I am using. The `if` statement is an empty block with the comment you see here.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const processFile = file => (
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file);

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: fileStream,
    });

    // Create a dummy lookup object.
    const lookupObj = { abc: 123 };

    rl.on('line', (line) => {
      // Split the line by tab to access fields.
      const [id] = line.split('\t');

      // Get the value for the 'id' field in my lookup object. It may or may not exist.
      const value = lookupObj[id];

      if (value) {
        /* do some stuff with 'value' */
      }
    });

    rl.on('close', () => {
      console.log(process.memoryUsage());
      resolve();
    });
  })
);
```

#### Don't use the destructured value (no leak)

I'm only showing the "line" event handler here. All else is the same as above.

```
rl.on('line', (line) => {
   // Split the line by tab to access fields.
   const [id] = line.split('\t');

   // Use 'line' itself as my lookup ID.
   const value = lookupObj[line];

   if (value) {
     /* do some stuff with 'value' */
   }
});
```

#### Don't perform lookup (no leak)

```
rl.on('line', (line) => {
   // Split the line by tab to access fields.
   const [id] = line.split('\t');

   // Use 'id' as my value with no lookup.
   const value = id;

   if (value) {
     /* do some stuff with 'value' */
   }
});
```

#### Edit

I have been able to get around/solve the issue but hesitate to post it as an answer until I understand what is happening. If I use a `Map` instead of an `Object` for storing my lookup values, the leak doesn't occur. The relevant code is:

```
// Create a dummy lookup Map.
const lookup = new Map();
lookup.set('abc', 123);

rl.on('line', (line) => {
   const [id] = line.split('\t');

   if (lookup.has(id)) {
      const value = lookup.get(id);
     /* do some stuff with 'value' */
   }
});
```

Comment: This is weird and interesting. Well-written question btw!

Comment: My guess would be that using the string for property lookup puts it into some kind of "property name cache", while the `Map` might use a simple hash…

Comment: V8 developer here. I can take a look if you share instructions how to reproduce the issue (maybe by posting a script that generates a representative input file; or a function that generates representative lines on the fly, or similar).

Comment: Thanks for the offer of help. Unfortunately, when trying to create a minimal example for you, I can no longer reproduce the issue. The problematic snippet above was called from another function, and the nature of this call is somehow necessary to create the problem. I'll try to figure out what's happening before possibly wasting your time.

Comment: I don't know if I already solved it but that is because the library you use (readline) saves the information in buffer in memory https://geshan.com.np/blog/2021/10/nodejs-read-file-line-by-line/